# Google Chart and Chart.Js, Send C# variable to Script side in Asp .NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, charts, google-visualization, chart.js

I'm developing web application at ASP .Net Core 2.2. I have to stop at an issue because of being new in .Net Core.

ASP In the .Net Core, I have two int arrays in backend.

I want to show them through various graphs such as curved line and bar chart, but I couldn't evaluate them in the script structure while I could use the variables I took from class via @model.

```
//My Arrays I want to use each integers.

//x axis

int[] x_ekseni_olculen_yillar = { 1997, 2003, 2005, 2009, 2014, 2018, 2019 };


//y axis

int[] y_ekseni_ofke_katsayisi = { 1, 3, 5, 3, 1, 18, 9 };
```

As you can see in the two code blocks I have illustrated above, the data was entered into the code blocks. At this point, I want to manipulate the data through a set of data, instead of entering the data manually.
How do I pass the int arrays below into these code blocks? The elements of these int arrays will be obtained as a result of the calculation and how can I extract a curve from arrays in both Chart types?

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>`enter code here`
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model))` in js to serialize your model and get all data. Then organize the data into the format you want.

1.Assume you have model:

```
public class ChartData
{
    public int[] Data_Axis_X { get; set; }
    public int[] Data_Axis_Y { get; set; }

}
```

2.Your action:

```
public IActionResult MyChart()
    {
        var model = new ChartData
        {
            Data_Axis_X = new int[] { 1997, 2003, 2005, 2009, 2014, 2018, 2019 },
            Data_Axis_Y = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 3, 1, 18, 9 }
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

3.MyChart.cshtml(Remember to add a reference to jquery in your project)

```
@model ChartData
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
        var allData = [];
        allData.push(['Year', 'Sales']);


        $.each(model.data_Axis_X, function (index, item) {
            var array = [];
            array.push(item);
            array.push(model.data_Axis_Y[index]);
            allData.push(array);
            console.log(Alldata);
    });

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(allData);

        var options = {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            curveType: 'function',
            legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Results:

[image]